# Setting shortcut values in VBE using CTRL key

Tags: vba, vbe

As you may know, in the VBE if you right click on the tool bar and select customize, then right click on a tool bar button you can add an ampersand (&) in front of a letter to create a shortcut using the ALT key.

Is it possible to set a shortcut using the CTRL key?  If so, what's the symbol?

[image]

Comment: This is a Windows feature called Accelerator keys. They work with `Alt`.

Comment: You may try to assign some unused accelerator keys, and use a [keyboard remap app](https://www.google.com/search?q=remap+keyboard) to translate desired shortcuts to accelerator keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` ampersand isn't a *shortcut* or configurable *hotkey*, it's an *accelerator key*, which behaves that way (i.e. responds to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) at a rather low level, consistently across anything running on Windows.

No, you can't make *accelerator keys* work with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key - the VBE has no say in that.

What you want is to assign a *hotkey* to certain IDE commands.. unfortunately the VBE doesn't allow configuring its hotkeys as far as I know.

You could write a VBIDE add-in (in VB6 if 32-bit-only is fine, or in .NET through COM interop for compatibility with 64-bit hosts) that enhances the VBE with such an ability though, but as the main project manager for [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (which does have configurable hotkeys *for its own commands*) I have to say that writing a .NET VBIDE add-in is a bit of a mine field. It's *fun* though =)

Comment: Accelerator key must have slipped my mind when posting, thanks for the correction.  Adding a hotkey seems like far more work than I'm willing to do for this, but thanks for the through answer!